# In there a markdown syntax similar to &shy;?

Tags: html, syntax, markdown, mdxjs

I'm looking for a similar markdown syntax to `&shy;` in HTML.

I know there are hard breaks in markdown, but I'm looking for something that acts like `&shy;` or similar.

Comment: Which Markdown processor are you using? The answer depends a little on how you process Markdown and what output is generated.

Comment: OK this makes sense now. I'm using MDX. It's probably not supported there cause it's not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most Markdown processors can process any HTML entity, including `&shy;`. So you can use that.

[Demo using babelmark3](https://babelmark.github.io/?text=aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa%26shy%3Baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa)

An alternative is to insert the SOFT HYPHEN (U+00AD) Unicode character directly. However, the feasibility of this depends on how easy your OS and/or editor makes entering arbitrary Unicode characters.